# Regular expression for validation of a facebook page url

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate the facebook page url which should not consider http/https or www given or not?

I mean the following should be **accepted or valid**:

```
www.facebook.com/ABCDE
facebook.com/ABCDE
http://www.facebook.com/ABCDE
https://www.facebook.com/ABCDE
```

And following should **not be accepted or invalid**:

```
http://www.facebook.com/   => User name/page name not given
http://www.facebook.com/ABC   => User name/page name should have the minimum length of 5.
```

For the above requirement I'd made following regular expression, but it is not checking the User Name or Page Name which is the only problem. Rest is working fine:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/(([a-z\d.]{5,})?)$/
```

I am very new to Regular Expression, so don't have much idea about it.

Any type of help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular expressions are probably not the best way to do this.  I'll bet anything there's a Facebook API that can help you out.

Comment: @RobertP: Thanks for your valuable opinion, I'll try to look at that side as well.

Comment: That regex looks fine. What is your problem with it?

Comment: @rekire: It is not validating the User Name/Page Name, that is the only problem with that regex.

Comment: I see... Well like Robert said you need to use for that some facebook API.

Comment: After you have validated that it looks like facebook page/profile link, you can try connecting to it and checking server response (404 for non existing pages, 200 for valid ones)

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Thanks will look into that area too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse_url()` can help you with that.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "www.facebook.com/ABCDE",
    "facebook.com/ABCDE",
    "http://www.facebook.com/ABCDE",
    "https://www.facebook.com/ABCDE",
    "http://www.facebook.com/",
    "http://www.facebook.com/ABC"
);

foreach ($array as $link) {
    if (strpos($link, "http") === false) {
        $link = "http://" . $link; //parse_url requires a valid URL. A scheme is needed. Add if not already there.
    }
    $url = parse_url($link);
    if (!preg_match("/(www\.)?facebook\.com/", $url["host"])) {
        //Not a facebook URL
        echo "FALSE!";
    }
    elseif (strlen(trim($url["path"], "/")) < 5) {
        //Trailing path (slashes not included) is less than 5
        echo "FALSE!";
    }
    else {
        //None of the above
        echo "TRUE";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one (have not tested it, should work)

```
'~^(https?://)?(www\.)?facebook\.com/\w{5,}$~i'
```

\w is like [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Robert

Comment: Please explain, why this correct and simple solution is downgraded

Comment: https://facebook.com/boule.magique and https://facebook.com/boule-magique are two perfectly valid facebook URLs, which you regex rejects.